Website content shifted all the way to the left
I'm a solo WordPress web dev who's managing this website and noticed that the website content's header and body shift to the left. I'm not sure how this happened and any advice on how to fix this would help me a lot! Thx in advance

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The Answer by @rudtek went in the right direction. But i see no reason you would need the Padding anyway? It seems like removing
@media (min-width: 922px) {
    .ast-container {
        max-width: 1240px;
    }

fixes the majority of your problem. After that you need to remove
@media (min-width: 922px) {
    .ast-container {
        max-width: 1240px;
    }
}

and the White Border on the left is gone. You complained about the Text not being centered since it shiftet to the left, but this seems to be only subjektiv. If you look at the DOM placement you see that relative to the total Viewport it is indeed now centered

Unfortunately removing it didn't make a difference. I did check my theme and realized that in the settings portion, there was an attribute that I set to auto that fixed it.
I was also confused about how you mentioned the same @media content twice asking me to remove it the first time. I do appreciate the help though

You've set a max width but you didn't adjust margins:
@media (min-width: 922px) {
  .ast-container {
    max-width: 1240px;
  }
}

should be
@media (min-width: 922px) {
  .ast-container {
    max-width: 1240px;
    margin: auto 0;
  }
}


This leaves just a little white space on the left hand so it partially fixes the issue but not entirely. It also makes my booking page content shift to the left instead of staying in the center
